# What apps can I remove in ubuntu headless?

Tags: raspberry-pi, headless

I'm running a headless version of ubuntu on a raspberrypi.  I keep running out of space on my 30GB SD main drive.  I am not sure why, and can only assume it's because maybe I have some packages installed that are not needed for headless ubuntu.  The only thing I can think of which I mistakenly installed was firefox, which I removed afterwards. I also see things like Gnome desktop themes installed, and as I don't know much about linux or ubuntu, I'm not sure what I can remove. I see X11 and xserver, for instance, and I am not sure if that is essential to ubuntu, or if that is something I've installed by mistake, or something that's included in the original install for some reason.

How do I search for and find packages I can uninstall to save space on my headless os?

Cheers!

Comment: If you can still afford it, I would suggest a reinstall. Maybe even a switch to Raspberry Pi OS - the light version is without desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Using +30 GB of space with a Raspberry Pi installation sounds like something other than the OS using space.  However, to remove the UI start with this:

`sudo apt remove --auto-remove --purge 'xserver*' 'x11*' 'gnome*' 'libx11*'`

That will remove most of the user interface.  You can get a listing of all the packages you have installed using `apt list --installed`.  This is a lengthy list.

As mentioned in the comments, it may be better to reinstall the OS using a [lite version](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/).

You might also consider trying to figure out where the space is being used, as I've never seen a Rasp Pi need 30 GB for the OS.  Try running the [disk usage (du) command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix)) to find where the space is being taken up.  Use `sudo du -h -d 1 /` to see the size of all root-level directories.  If it is `/usr` then you do have a lot of software installed.  If not, you have another problem such as a runway log file.